# Contact form submit succeed message by $post

Tags: php, ajax, post, submit

I'm having trouble to have the suceed message of submitting form,
I've been playing around and did kind of a mess certainly . .

What I'd liek is at the end, once submitting the form, to make the form dissapear, and appear a message instread saying ( Congratulation, the submission has been done)

My html:

```
<div class="questionContainer radius">
<div class="question"><b>Question 1:</b> Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript?</div>
<div class="answers">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-a" />&lt;js&gt;</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-b" />&lt;script&gt;</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-c" />&lt;scripting&gt;</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-d" />&lt;javascript&gt;</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="btnContainer">
    <div class="next">
        <a class="btnNext">Next &gt;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="questionContainer hide radius">
<div class="question"><b>Question 2:</b> What is the correct JavaScript syntax to write "Hello World"?</div>
<div class="answers">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-a" />response.write("Hello World")</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-b" />("Hello World")</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-c" />"Hello World"</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-d" />document.write("Hello World")</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="btnContainer">
    <div class="prev">
        <a class="btnPrev">&lt; Prev</a>
    </div>
    <div class="next">
        <a class="btnNext">Next &gt;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
 </div>
 <div class="questionContainer radius hide">
<div class="question"><b>Question 3:</b> Where is the correct place to insert a JavaScript?</div>
<div class="answers">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3-a" />Both the &lt;thead&gt; section and the &lt;body&gt; section are correct</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3-b" />The &lt;body&gt; section</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3-c" />The &lt;head&gt; section</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="btnContainer">
    <div class="prev">
        <a class="btnPrev">&lt;&lt; Prev</a>
    </div>
    <div class="next">
        <a class="btnNext">Next &gt;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="questionContainer radius hide">
<div class="question"><b>Question 4:</b> What is the correct syntax for referring to an external script called "xxx.js"?</div>
<div class="answers">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q4" id="q4-a" />&lt;script type="text/javascript" name="xxx.js"&gt;</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q4" id="q4-b" />&lt;script type="text/javascript" href="xxx.js"&gt;</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q4" id="q4-c" />&lt;script type="text/javascript" src="xxx.js"&gt;</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="btnContainer">
    <div class="prev">
        <a class="btnPrev">&lt; Prev</a>
    </div>
    <div class="next">
        <a class="btnNext">Next &gt;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
 </div>
<div class="questionContainer radius hide">
<div class="question"><b>Question 5:</b> The external JavaScript file must contain the &lt;script&gt; tag?</div>
<div class="answers">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q5" id="q5-a" />True</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="radio" name="q5" id="q5-b" />False</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



<div class="btnContainer">
    <div class="prev">
        <a class="btnPrev">&lt;&lt; Prev</a>
    </div>
  <div class="next">
        <a class="btnNext">Next!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="questionContainer radius hide">
 <form action="submit.php" method="POST" id="quesForm">
 <label>Name</label>
 <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Type Here"><br/>
 <label>Email</label>
 <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here"><br/>
 <label>Phone</label>
 <input name="message" placeholder="Type Here">
 <input id="button"  type="submit" value="Send" class="btnShowResult" >
 </form>
  <div class="btnContainer">
    <div class="prev">
        <a class="btnPrev">&lt;&lt; Prev</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
   </div>

<div id="responseMessage"> Your submission has been done, thank you</div>

<div class="txtStatusBar">Status Bar</div>
<div id="progressKeeper" class="radius">
<div id="progress"></div>
</div>
<div id="resultKeeper" class="radius hide"></div>
</div>
```

and my CSS for the div:

```
#responseMessage{
display:none;}
```

here is my Jquery

```
$(function() {
$('#quesForm').on('submit',function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();
// I am fetching the form values you could get them by other selectors too
var uname = $("input[name=username]").val(); 
var uemail = $("input[name=email]").val();
var msg = $("input[name=message]").val()
$.post('submit.php',{username:uname,email:uemail,message:msg,results:$('#resultKeeper').html(),subject:'Subject   of your e-mail'},function(result){
      // result variable contains your response text
      // I guess you trying to update your response 
     // notice I have used html(result) as you have just used html()
      $('#responseMessage').html(result);

});
  // you dont require `return false`
  // you have already did it using e.preventDefault();
});
  });
```

and My Php

```
<?php $name = $_POST['username'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $results = $_POST['results'];
   $results = strip_tags($results); // add this to remove html tags and all
   $formcontent="From: $name \n Phone: $message \n Results: \n $results";
   $recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
   $subject = "my subject";
   $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
   mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
   echo "Your email has been send, thank you";
 ?>
```

I Tried with includinb a div #responseMessage with a visibility:hidden , but nothing . ..

Will really appreciate any helps,

Thank you so much !

Comment: can you add html also?

Comment: I've just edit, thank you for your time, really appreciate =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not hide your form. you need to hide your form and show your result in your div.  You need to replace id_of_your_form by the id of your form.

```
 $(function() {
    $('#quesForm').on('submit',function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    // I am fetching the form values you could get them by other selectors too
    var uname = $("input[name=username]").val(); 
    var uemail = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var msg = $("input[name=message]").val()
    $.post('submit.php',{username:uname,email:uemail,message:msg,results:$('#resultKeeper').html(),subject:'Subject   of your e-mail'},function(result){
          // result variable contains your response text
          // I guess you trying to update your response 
         // notice I have used html(result) as you have just used html()
          $('#id_of_your_form').hide();
          $('#responseMessage').show();
          $('#responseMessage').html(result);

    });
      // you dont require `return false`
      // you have already did it using e.preventDefault();
    });
      });
```

Comment: Thank you, it's almost there, The form hide when submit, but the  #responseMessage doesn't appear . .. it's not hidden since the beginning, don't know why . ..  I've update my post with the Html and CSS . . Thank you for your time Awlad =)

Comment: then you have error in your php page. It did not send mail properly

Comment: Do you know how to fix that by any chance ? Thing is my div responseMessage doesn't hide at all . . event with visibility:hidden or display:none and !important value . . .

Comment: allright, I manage to make my div #responseMessage hidden, but on submission it doesn't appear . . .

Comment: @tibewww : i have updated my answer it  will show message div